# A Django app to take user uploaded locatio

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to build a Django app to allow users upload their locations which will later be displayed on a map. I would also like to have a search feature where visitors can search and find those uploaded locations. Any help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need three flows basically. For simplicity I am assuming that we only keep track of the most recently seen user location

> allow users upload their locations

The frontend makes a request to the backend with the current user location OR the backend figures out the rough location via the IP.

Either way the backend then takes the location coordinates and stores it in a datastore with the user_id as a lookup key

> which will later be displayed on a map.

The frontend requests the required locations from the backend. The backend grabs the data from the same datastore and sends it to the frontend as json - the frontend then uses a library such as mapbox to display the locations

> search feature where visitors can search

Here the key is to have some sort of datastore that can compute georadius. This can be Postgis via postgres, or geohash via redis, or a custom kdtree type service.

But either way the frontend would send the location + some distance threshold - and then this service would figure out all locations within that threshold and return that as a response

Comment: Thanks so much. I want all the uploaded locations to all appear on the map. I want to build something quite similar to apartments.com website